# Is there a way to 'close'/accept answered, abandoned questions?

Tags: support

Lots of questions that are put on the frontpage by 'Community' are old questions that have answeres but none are accepted. They've been abandoned by the original asker, and they're useless to build on, but they're perfectly fine to keep. Is there a way of accepting an answer on behalf of the original user so the question will not pop up again?

Comment: If they're bumped by community it means they've not got anything upvoted - chuck an unvote on it and it won't be bumped again.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As far as I'm aware community 'bumps' questions for which there are no answers. The SE definition of no answers is no accepted or upvoted answers.

If as you suggest, they are worth keeping around. then chuck an upvote on a suitable answer (or more than one), then Community will have done it's job and the Q&A will sink into the database.

If the Q&A is of no value, then it can be closed or downvoted and deletd in the usual manner.

Only the OP can accept an answer.

Comment: This five year old question got bumped by `Community`, even though it has four upvoted answers, one of which is accepted: http://serverfault.com/questions/57729/risk-of-using-ssh-public-keys

Comment: @kasperd  You can't see it, it was bumped by a spammer. The post was deleted and the account nuked.

Comment: I wonder why it doesn't drop off the active questions list when that post got deleted. When spam gets deleted the post should look as if it never happened.

Comment: @kasperd you would have to discuss that with SE, my guess would be that it is all part of the community oversight.

Answer (score 9):

If you look, there is a pattern to what gets pushed by Community: none of the answers have upvotes. All it takes is throwing an upvote on the best answer of the lot and it won't resurface!

Comment: Having a rough morning? I haven't seen you this snarky in months.

Comment: @ChrisS sysadmin1138 must be a nice guy, if this counts as snarky. I have come across other people online who are more snarky than that, when they are in a good mood.